# Chat with Google Talk clients using XMPPframework

Tags: iphone, ios4, xmpp, google-talk

How would I go about implementing a chat client for the iPhone that can use the XMPPframework to chat with other Google Talk clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site for XMPPFramework actually has pretty good documentation. Have you looked at the [introduction](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/IntroToFramework) and the [getting started instructions for iOS](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS)?